# Adding from a json file to make a new json file

Tags: c++, package.json, org.json

I am trying to make a system for an airport and I want to add flights.

To add these flights I must make a new flights.json file that will contain some data entered by the user and then the user must choose from some of the available data from another airports.json file to make a flights.json entry.

My problem is that I don't know how to provide the user with some entries from the airports.json file so the user can choose from that and then the programme should automatically add the users chosen data and complete the flights.json file entry

```
#include <iostream>
#include "json.hpp"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "login.h"
#include <string>
using json = nlohmann::json;
json jj;
int date,month,year,flyingout_hour,flyingout_minute,flyingin_hour,flyingin_minute,choice;


void flights_add()
{
    std::cout << "\n enter flying out date\n";
    std::cin >> date;
    while (date >= 31) {
        std::cin >> date;
    }
    std::cout << "\n enter flying out month\n";
    std::cin >> month;
    std::cout << "\n enter flight year\n";
    std::cin >> year;
    std::cout << "\n enter flying out time\n";
    std::cout << "hour(24h format):";
    std::cin >> flyingout_hour;
    std::cout << "minute(60 min format):";
    std::cin >> flyingout_minute;
    std::cout << "\n enter flying in time \n";
    std::cout << "hour(24h formata):";
    std::cin >> flyingin_hour;
    std::cout << "minute(60 min formata):";
    std::cin >> flyingin_minute;

    std::cout << "\n enter direction from \n";
    std::ifstream i("airports.json");
    if (i.is_open()) {


        i >> jj;
    }
    std::cout << airports.dump(1) << std::endl;


std::cin >> choice;


    std::cout << "\nenter direction to\n";
    std::cout << "\nwhich plane will fly?\n";
}
```

Comment: This is more of a story, not so much a question. Try to form some kind of questiony sentence in there. Just be aware that questions along the lines of "can you complete my assignment for me?" tend to be answered with a rather forceful "no" around here.

Comment: So... you got the json file read into the jj object, you are using a library, which is nice. What is unclear to you? How to access the airports data inside the jj object? That depens on the exact structure of the json file which you have not shown us. Or how best to present it to the user for selection?